# Areas in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am going to build an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application with SQL Server 2019. The possible users of my application are employees and students.

The employees may be teachers, accountants, managers. The employees may be in different offices. Now I am confused to map separate roles of users and application modules.

My application deals with examinations, payroll, attendance, and some academic tasks. An ASP.NET Core MVC application gives the option of areas.

Should I use areas for distinct roles or a new project for each role? I am confused how to work around modules, projects, and areas. Can anybody help me resolve my confusion?

Comment: Greetings, Fayyaz (et al)! Before providing an "answer" for review, have you considered using authorization rules on your individual Controllers and/or Actions themselves rather than branching off into separate Areas based upon job function?  You may be able to accomplish the task by simply restricting access via authorization filters.  For more information, please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-6.0.

Comment: Yes, I have added authorization......

Comment: All things considered, I would recommend mapping out whether or not an "Admin" area would suffice, locking down Controllers by Role, instead of the overhead included with additional Area objects for each Role themselves.  What are your thoughts about something like that?

Comment: This is better way I think